# Not in scope: type constructor or class `GenUnchecked'

Tags: haskell, property-based-testing

I want to set up property based testing using [validity](https://github.com/NorfairKing/validity), but I'm having trouble getting even this simple example from the documentation to compile:

```hs
module PrimeSpec where

import Data.GenValidity
import Data.Validity
import Data.Numbers.Primes
import Test.QuickCheck

newtype Prime = Prime Int

instance Validity Prime where
  validate (Prime n) = declare "The 'Int' is prime." $ isPrime n

instance GenUnchecked Prime where
  genUnchecked = Prime <$> arbitrary

instance GenValid Prime where
  genValid = Prime <$> (oneof [
    pure 2,
    ((\y -> 2 * abs y + 1) <$> arbitrary) `suchThat` isPrime])
```

The code above fails with:

```
    Not in scope: type constructor or class `GenUnchecked'
   |
13 | instance GenUnchecked Prime where
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So I guess I need to import it. I usually do this via hoogle, but `GenUnchecked` is [not listed there](https://hoogle.haskell.org/?hoogle=GenUnchecked). And it's [not listed on hackage](https://hackage.haskell.org/packages/search?terms=GenUnchecked) either. But the hackage documentation for `genvalidity` has it listed [right here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/genvalidity-0.5.0.0/docs/Data-GenValidity.html#t:GenUnchecked) in the module `Data.Validity` (which I imported) and the package `genvalidity` (which I added to my `package.yaml`).

Maybe there are some version conflicts? But I don't know how to check the versions of the installed packages, because I'm fairly new to haskell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking at the docs of version 0.5.0.0 which is almost 5 years old (you can tell from the URL, the title, and from the style of the page). [The latest version of `genvalidity` is 1.1.0.0](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/genvalidity-1.1.0.0/docs/Data-GenValidity.html).

Comment: Oh boy... do you happen to know any getting started tutorial on validity? All I kind find seems to be outdated.

Comment: Are you familiar with QuickCheck and hspec? If not, those would be helpful to look into, since validity is depends on them. Maybe also try emailing the author of validity.